# How can I list private zones associated with a VPC that are hosted in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-route53

I can use a set of AWS API commands to associate a VPC with a private zone 
hosted in another account. That way, name resolution works in the VPC even for the zones that are defined elsewhere.

Here's the relevant documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/private-hosted-zone-different-account/

However, I have no idea how I can see what zones a given VPC is associated with. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

The association is at least listed in the Route53 console (webinterface) in the "Hosted Zone Details" under "Associated VPCs".

Not exactly what I asked for as it doesn't list the associations from the point of the receiving VPC, but it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't, at least not with the API. Wrote about this here: https://blog.ryanjarv.sh/2019/05/24/backdooring-route53-with-cross-account-dns.html